# I want to create a dynamically trigger in java

Tags: sql, triggers, firebird

I want to create a Trigger (firebird) in java by using a created sequence (SEQUENCE_NUMERO).
Here is my code:

```
try (Statement stmt = avonnection.createStatement())
{
    stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE  TRIGGER NEXTVALUE" + "BEFORE INSERT ON PERSONNE"
                        + "\nFOR EACH ROW "
                        + "\nBEGIN "
                        + "\nNEW.NUMERO_= SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NUMERO FROM RDB$DATABASE;"
                        + "\nEND NEXTVALUE; "
                        + "/");
}
```

But I have this exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Dynamic SQL Error; SQL error code = -104; Token unknown - line 2, column 1; FOR [SQLState:42000, ISC error code:335544634]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:527)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:302)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:138)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:202)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readSingleResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:169)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:153)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readGenericResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:255)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractFbWireDatabase.readGenericResponse(AbstractFbWireDatabase.java:173)
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version11.V11Statement.prepare(V11Statement.java:89)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.prepareFixedStatement(FBStatement.java:1370)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.internalExecute(FBStatement.java:1356)
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBStatement.executeUpdate(FBStatement.java:280)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:118)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

I try to created a trigger which will work after each insertion

Comment: You have no space between NEXTVALUE and BEFORE. So it probably sees CREATE TRIGGER NEXTVALUEBEFORE INSERT ON PERSONNE...

Comment: I put a space but I ave always the same exception.

Comment: I tried to test empty body (to put nothing between begin and end), But, I had the same problem

Comment: I think you have the wrong syntax. This is the [correct one](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-create-trigger.html).

Comment: @RealSkeptic That is pretty old documentation, more up-to-date is [`CREATE TRIGGER` in the Firebird 4.0 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-trigger.html#fblangref40-ddl-trgr-create)

Comment: The syntax you're using is not the Firebird trigger syntax, it looks like the MySQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should fix the syntax problems you're having

```
CREATE TRIGGER NEXTVALUE FOR PERSONNE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
NEW.NUMERO_ = NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NUMERO;
END
```

as noted in the comments [Next value](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-commons.html#fblangref40-commons-nxtvlufor) from sequence can be fetched without the select query as well, so you could change it from

```
(SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NUMERO FROM RDB$DATABASE);
```

Comment: There is no need to use a select here, `next value for SEQUENCE_NUMERO` can be used directly in PSQL (i.e. `NEW.NUMERO = next value for SEQUENCE_NUMERO;`).

Comment: Thank you.
All are OK by using trigger.


Now I want to find another solution without using TRIGGER.

Always with Firebird, I wrote follwing Hql in java: 

SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NUMERO  FROM RDB$DATABASE
The query works very well in DBeaver.

But, when I try to execute this query in Java, I have the following exception:
```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: VALUE near line 1, column 13 [SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SEQUENCE_NUMERO FROM RDB$DATABASE]